# Find parameter so that the equation has roots in arithmetic progression

Tags: polynomials, roots, arithmetic-progressions

Find the parameter $m$ so that the equation
$$x^8 - mx^4 + m^4 = 0$$
has four distinct real roots in arithmetic progression.

I tried the substitution $x^4 = y$, so the equation becomes

$$y^2 -my  + m^4 = 0$$

I don't know what condition should I put now or if this is a correct approach.

I have also tried to use Viete's by the notation $$2x_2=x_1+x_2, 2x_3=x_2 +x_4$$ but I didn't get much out of it.

Comment: So quadratic equation's roots are given by
$$
y = \frac{m \pm \sqrt{m^2 - 4m^4}}{2} = \frac{m \pm m\sqrt{1 - 4m^2}}{2}
$$
and $x = y^{1/4}$ can you perhaps try to find the roots and pick some $m$ to get a progression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero can't be a root, else $m=0$, in which case all the roots would be zero.

If $r$ is any root, so is $ri$, hence there must be exactly $4$ real roots, and $4$ pure imaginary roots.

Also, if $r$ is a root, so is $-r$, hence the real roots sum to zero.

Ordering the real roots in ascending order, let $d > 0$ be the common difference.

Then the four real roots are

$$-\frac{3}{2}d,\;-\frac{1}{2}d,\;\frac{1}{2}d,\;\frac{3}{2}d$$

and the other four roots are

$$-\frac{3}{2}di,\;-\frac{1}{2}di,\;\frac{1}{2}di,\;\frac{3}{2}di$$

Since the $4$-th powers of the roots satisfy the quadratic

$$y^2 - my + m^4 = 0$$

Vieta's formulas yields the equations

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}d\right)^4+\left(\frac{3}{2}d\right)^4 = m$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}d\right)^4\left(\frac{3}{2}d\right)^4 = m^4$$

$$\text{or, in simpler form}$$

$$\frac{41}{8}d^4 = m\tag{eq1}$$

$$\frac{81}{256}d^8 = m^4\tag{eq2}$$

Solving $(\text{eq}1)$ for $d^4$, substituting the result into $(\text{eq}2)$, and then solving for $m$ yields
$$m = \frac{9}{82}$$

Comment: Where does that $\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$ and so on come from ?

Comment: The $4$-th power of _any_ root of the original polynomial is a root of the quadratic. In particular $\left(\frac{1}{2}d\right)^4$ and $\left(\frac{3}{2}d\right)^4$ are roots of the quadratic.

Comment: Perhaps you're asking why the real roots are
$$-\frac{3}{2}d,\;-\frac{1}{2}d,\;\frac{1}{2}d,\;\frac{3}{2}d$$
That's because the 4 real roots sum to zero. Since the real roots sum to zero, their average is zero. But the real roots are in arithmetic progression with common difference $d > 0$.

Comment: Yes, but from where does that $3/2$ come from ? You just assumed the roots so the sum equals $0$ ?

Comment: Any arithmetic progression is symmetrical about its average value. Since in this case, the average value is 0, and the common difference is d, the two middle terms must be $-\frac{1}{2}d$ and $\frac{1}{2}d$, respectively. Then just apply the common difference to get the first and last terms.

Comment: Should we come to the same result, if we took for example the middle values to be $1$ and $-1$, since they are also symmetrical but make the calculations easier? Or is there a reason for choosing $1/2$ and $-1/2$?

Comment: You have no choice of $d$; it needs to be unknown. Later, you can actually find the value of $d$ (using the derived value of $m$ and any one of the equations relating $d$ and $m$). You'll see that the actual value of $d$ is not equal to $1$.

Comment: The common difference is $d$. The average value of the terms of the progression is zero, hence, by symmetry, zero must be half way between the middle terms. Since the middle terms are $d$ apart, the distance from each of them to zero is $\frac{1}{2}d$.

Comment: I meant choosing the division so the roots are as follows $-3d, - 1d, 1d, 3d$ and $-3di, - 1di, 1di, 3di$. Such that the division becomes $2$, as opposed to $1$ which was in your response.

Comment: Sure, you can do that (i.e., let $2d$ be the common difference). It avoids the fractions, but it's no big deal either way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0 < a < b$ be the roots of $y^2 - m y + m^4$ (note that $0 < m < 1/2$ is needed for these to be real and positive).  Then the real roots of $x^8 - m x^4 + m^4$ are (in order) $-b^{1/4}, -a^{1/4}, a^{1/4}, b^{1/4}$.
  These are in a.p. iff $2 a^{1/4} = b^{1/4} - a^{1/4}$, i.e. $b = 3^4 a$.
That turns out to be true for $m = 9/82$.